# How do I write a script to open a pgp file with gvim?

Tags: vim, pgp

I have a pgp encrypted text file that needs to be read by someone who is not comfortable with vim or the command line, though I think gvim will work for their needs.  I edit the file using vim and the gnupg.vim plugin.  According to the gnupg.vim documentation:

In some cases gvim can't decrypt files

This is caused by the fact that a running gvim has no TTY and thus gpg is
  not able to ask for the passphrase by itself. This is a problem for Windows
  and Linux versions of gvim and could not be solved unless a "terminal
  emulation" is implemented for gvim. To circumvent this you have to use any
  combination of gpg-agent and a graphical pinentry program:

```
- gpg-agent only:
    you need to provide the passphrase for the needed key to gpg-agent
    in a terminal before you open files with gvim which require this key.

- pinentry only:
    you will get a popup window every time you open a file that needs to
    be decrypted.

- gpgagent and pinentry:
    you will get a popup window the first time you open a file that
    needs to be decrypted.
```

I  have pinentry-gnome3 installed on my machine, but it doesn't seem to work when I use vim or gvim, at least no gui pops up to request the password.  When I try opening my pgp file with gvim I simply get an error telling me that the file could not be unencrypted.

The pinentry and gpg-agent man pages both indicate that they are called by other scripts and not manually.  So, I am not sure how to get gvim to use them when trying to open my pgp file, especially in a script that can be called by users unfamiliar with the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (pgp.exe is from 1996)
c:> pgp -z"passphrase" -c file.pgp